# Flutter tests throw "Bad state: Future already completed" when testing a call to `notifyListeners`

Tags: flutter, flutter-test

I am trying to test a class with a function like that

```dart
class A {
  void doStuff() {
    // Do stuff...
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I am currently using the `flutter-test` package to automate my tests.
My test looks like this:

```dart
void main() {
  final myInstance = A();

  group("Class A", () {
    test("should correctly do stuff", () async {
      myInstance.doStuff();
      expect(...);
    });
  });
}
```

The test is working and `expect` yields the correct result.
However, console shows an error message:

> The following StateError was thrown while dispatching notifications for Class A: 
> Bad state: Future already completed

What causes this error and how can I prevent it from happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, `notifyListeners()` was the root-cause here.
It threw an error, presumably because it was not yet initialized.

By waiting for its initialization, the error has stopped occuring.
See [`TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestWidgetsFlutterBinding/ensureInitialized.html) for reference

```dart
setUpAll(() {
  TestWidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
});
```